# Как при наведении на элемент выделить его соседние элементы так, что бы получилась определенная фигура?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(cols, rows, gap) {
    this.cols = cols
    this.rows = rows
    this.gap = gap

    this.grid = null
    this.cells = []

    this.mouseEnterHandler = this.mouseEnterHandler.bind(this)
    this.mouseLeaveHandler = this.mouseLeaveHandler.bind(this)
  }

  init(parent) {
    this.createCells()
    this.createGrid()

    this.grid.append(...this.cells)

    parent.prepend(this.grid)
  }

  createGrid() {
    this.grid = document.createElement('div')
    this.grid.style.display = 'grid'
    this.grid.style.height = '100%'
    this.grid.style.width = '100%'
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${this.cols}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${this.rows}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridGap = `${this.gap}px`
  }

  createCells() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows * this.cols; i++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
      cell.id = i
      cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseEnterHandler)
      cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeaveHandler)

      this.cells.push(cell)
    }
  }

  mouseEnterHandler(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen'
  }

  mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
  }
}

const grid = new Grid(20, 20, 3)
grid.init(document.body)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Такая, например
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои попытки сделать хоть какую-нибудь фигурку

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(cols, rows, gap) {
    this.cols = cols
    this.rows = rows
    this.gap = gap

    this.grid = null
    this.cells = []

    this.hoveredElements = []
    this.hoveredElement = null

    this.mouseEnterHandler = this.mouseEnterHandler.bind(this)
    this.mouseLeaveHandler = this.mouseLeaveHandler.bind(this)
  }

  init(parent) {
    this.createCells()
    this.createGrid()

    this.grid.append(...this.cells)

    parent.prepend(this.grid)
  }

  createGrid() {
    this.grid = document.createElement('div')
    this.grid.style.display = 'grid'
    this.grid.style.height = '100%'
    this.grid.style.width = '100%'
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${this.cols}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${this.rows}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridGap = `${this.gap}px`
  }

  createCells() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows * this.cols; i++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
      cell.id = i
      cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseEnterHandler)
      cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeaveHandler)

      this.cells.push(cell)
    }
  }

  mouseEnterHandler(e) {
    const targetBox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()

    this.cells.forEach((cell) => {
      const cellBox = cell.getBoundingClientRect()

      if (
        targetBox.left - 100 <= cellBox.right &&
        cellBox.right <= targetBox.left &&
        targetBox.top == cellBox.top ||

        targetBox.right + 100 >= cellBox.left &&
        cellBox.left >= targetBox.right &&
        targetBox.top == cellBox.top ||

        targetBox.top - 100 <= cellBox.bottom &&
        cellBox.bottom <= targetBox.top &&
        targetBox.left == cellBox.left ||

        targetBox.bottom + 100 >= cellBox.top &&
        cellBox.top >= targetBox.bottom &&
         targetBox.left == cellBox.left
      ) {
        this.hoveredElements.push(cell)
      }
    })


    this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
    })
  }

  mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
    this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
    })

    this.hoveredElements = []
  }
}

const grid = new Grid(20, 20, 3)
grid.init(document.body)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот например при помощи такой проверки

[Manhattan Distance](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```
let x = e.target.id % this.cols;
let y = (e.target.id / this.rows) | 0;
this.cells.forEach((cell) => {
  let cx = cell.id % this.cols;
  let cy = (cell.id / this.rows) | 0;
  if (Math.abs(cx - x) + Math.abs(cy - y) < 4) {
    this.hoveredElements.push(cell)
  }
})
```

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(cols, rows, gap) {
    this.cols = cols
    this.rows = rows
    this.gap = gap

    this.grid = null
    this.cells = []

    this.hoveredElements = []
    this.hoveredElement = null

    this.mouseEnterHandler = this.mouseEnterHandler.bind(this)
    this.mouseLeaveHandler = this.mouseLeaveHandler.bind(this)
  }

  init(parent) {
    this.createCells()
    this.createGrid()

    this.grid.append(...this.cells)

    parent.prepend(this.grid)
  }

  createGrid() {
    this.grid = document.createElement('div')
    this.grid.style.display = 'grid'
    this.grid.style.height = '100%'
    this.grid.style.width = '100%'
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${this.cols}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${this.rows}, 1fr)`
    this.grid.style.gridGap = `${this.gap}px`
  }

  createCells() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows * this.cols; i++) {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
      cell.id = i
      cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseEnterHandler)
      cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeaveHandler)

      this.cells.push(cell)
    }
  }

  mouseEnterHandler(e) {
  
    let x = e.target.id % this.cols;
    let y = (e.target.id / this.rows) | 0;
    this.cells.forEach((cell) => {
      let cx = cell.id % this.cols;
      let cy = (cell.id / this.rows) | 0;
      if (Math.abs(cx - x) + Math.abs(cy - y) < 3) {
        this.hoveredElements.push(cell)
      }
    })


    this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
    })
  }

  mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
    this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
    })

    this.hoveredElements = []
  }
}

const grid = new Grid(20, 20, 3)
grid.init(document.body)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: `Побитовое или` здесь вместо `Math.floor`? Как это работает?

Comment: оно приводит число к целому =) перед или

Comment: За счет чего?))) По смыслу должно возвращать то же число. То есть отбрасывает дробную часть?

Comment: @Leonid https://i.imgur.com/nh6CmI9.png скин отсюда https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: @Leonid это Вы растр векторизуете? я для этого готовые либы использовал только, сам не писал, это что-то вроде hough transform?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106528/discussion-between-leonid-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: Спасибо. Выглядит как всегда устрашающе. Утром на пк попробую победить этого монстра)

Comment: @hu-fo формула крайне простая, если бы изначально был не индекс а xy было бы еще проще, а еще лучше делать через `array.filter`

Comment: А что если это была бы другая фигура? Буква "К", например? Тогда составлять массив этих элементов по дельте от нуля, а потом находить каждый из этих элементов согласно карте и измененного положения целевого элемента?

Comment: @Leonid я бы назвал это маской, и брал бы ячейки не перебором, а сразу, по необходимым координатам

Answer (score 7):

Можно составить маску любой фигуры (так я вижу букву К):

```
this.mask = [[-1,-2],[-1,-1],[-1, 0],[-1,1],[-1,2],[0,0],[1,-1],[2,-2],[1, 1],[2,2]];
```

И переписать `mouseEnterHandler` следующим образом:

```
  mouseEnterHandler(e) {

    let x = e.target.id % this.cols;       // Получаем х координату mouseover элемента
    let y = Math.floor(e.target.id / this.rows); // Получаем y координату 
    this.mask.forEach(item => {  // Перебираем позиции маски
        let itemX = x + item[0]; // Определяем x координату элемента по дельте из маски
        let itemY = y + item[1]; // Определяем y координату
        // Проверяем не выходит ли элемент за пределы сетки
        // Можно было потом проверить на существование по id, но мало ли где еще будут использоваться такие (числовые) id
        if(itemX >= 0 && itemX < this.cols && itemY >= 0 && itemY < this.rows){
            let order = +e.target.id + item[0] + item[1]*this.cols; // Находим порядковый номер
            let cell = document.getElementById(order); // Получаем элемент по id = порядковый номер
            this.hoveredElements.push(cell); // Закидываем в массив для последующего изменения style
        }

    })

    this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {  // Здесь перебираются элементы из массива this.hoveredElements
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    })
  }
```

```js
class Grid {
  constructor(cols, rows, gap) {
this.cols = cols
this.rows = rows
this.gap = gap

this.grid = null
this.cells = []

this.hoveredElements = []
this.hoveredElement = null

this.mouseEnterHandler = this.mouseEnterHandler.bind(this)
this.mouseLeaveHandler = this.mouseLeaveHandler.bind(this)
this.mask = [[-1,-2],[-1,-1],[-1, 0],[-1,1],[-1,2],[0,0],[1,-1],[2,-2],[1, 1],[2,2]];
  }

  init(parent) {
this.createCells()
this.createGrid()

this.grid.append(...this.cells)

parent.prepend(this.grid)
  }

  createGrid() {
this.grid = document.createElement('div')
this.grid.style.display = 'grid'
this.grid.style.height = '100%'
this.grid.style.width = '100%'
this.grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${this.cols}, 1fr)`
this.grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${this.rows}, 1fr)`
this.grid.style.gridGap = `${this.gap}px`
  }

  createCells() {
for (let i = 0; i < this.rows * this.cols; i++) {
  const cell = document.createElement('div')
  cell.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
  cell.id = i
  cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseEnterHandler)
  cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeaveHandler)

  this.cells.push(cell)
}
  }

  mouseEnterHandler(e) {
  
let x = e.target.id % this.cols;       // Получаем х координату mouseover элемента
let y = Math.floor(e.target.id / this.rows); // Получаем y координату 
this.mask.forEach(item => {  // Перебираем позиции маски
    let itemX = x + item[0]; // Определяем x координату элемента по дельте из маски
    let itemY = y + item[1]; // Определяем y координату
    // Проверяем не выходит ли элемент за пределы сетки
    // Можно было потом проверить на существование по id, но мало ли где еще будут использоваться такие (числовые) id
    if(itemX >= 0 && itemX < this.cols && itemY >= 0 && itemY < this.rows){
        let order = +e.target.id + item[0] + item[1]*this.cols; // Находим порядковый номер
        let cell = document.getElementById(order); // Получаем элемент по id = порядковый номер
        this.hoveredElements.push(cell); // Закидываем в массив для последующего изменения style
    }

})

this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {  // Здесь перебираются элементы из массива this.hoveredElements
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
})
  }

  mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
this.hoveredElements.forEach((element) => {
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
})

this.hoveredElements = []
  }
}

const grid = new Grid(20, 20, 1)
grid.init(document.body)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Не удержался и предложил такой вариант. В конце концов здесь можно устанавливать свои любые фигуры.